# When I extract .tar.gz all of the files within the folders have the .gz suffix

Tags: linux, gzip, tar

I have recently begun using a VPS and am learning linux along the way. I have compressed a folder using tar, then I gzipped it and used scp to send it to my server. When I decompress using tar -zxvf .tar.gz, all of the files within the folder still have .gz . Am I compressing the folder wrong to begin with?

Comment: This should probably have been asked on http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Try a "tar -tvzf" on your archive and check if the files inside the archive are individually gzipped from their file names.  It's the only way I can think of that might make this happen, although I'm not sure how you would have gzipped each file while compressing.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you first `gzip`ped the files inside the folder, then used `tar` and then again `gzip`ped the tar file? Something like this:

```
gzip folder/*
tar -cvf folder.tar folder
gzip folder.tar
```

If yes - the first `gzip` was too much. You should simply do:

```
tar -cvf folder.tar folder
gzip folder.tar
```

Or even simpler

```
tar -cvzf folder.tar.gz folder
```

Comment: Not sure how, but it looks like that is exactly what I did. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: ...and the command to extract this file is `tar xvzf folder.tar.gz`. `v` = verbose (print the names of the files as they are extracted), `z` = gzip file and `f folder.tar.gz` specifies the file. See the [manual page on tar](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are compressing the folder wrong to begin with. You can do it correctly all in one step like this:

```
tar cvfz tarfile.tar.gz folder/
```

Comment: Will definitely use this single step in the future. Appreciate it.